# Detect when new user connects to irc in miniirc

Tags: python, bots, irc

I want to make an irc bot using [miniirc](https://pypi.org/project/miniirc/) and I need to detect when a user connects and give him voice.

Unfortunately I have no idea on how to detect when someone enters the chat and how to give him voice, I tried:

```
cmd = text[0].lower()
name = text[0]

# ...

@irc.Handler('PRIVMSG', colon=False)
def handle_privmsg(irc, hostmask, args):
    channel = args[0]
    
    text = args[-1].split(' ')
    name = text[0]
    if "joined" in text:
        irc.msg(channel, f'/voice {name}')
```

Comment: What was the problem with the code you've tried?

Comment: It does not work

Comment: @mkrieger1 it does not recognize input from the * user